# How to check object null value in xamarin forms data trigger?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

I'm trying to check if a binding object value is null in Xamarin Forms XAML DataTrigger but I can't get it to work. I have tried the following:

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="True">
    <StackLayout.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout"
                        Binding="{Binding MyObject}"
                        Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </StackLayout.Triggers>

    ...

</StackLayout>
```

Does anyone know a way to do it? I have tested this only on Android.

**Edit:** I have filed a bug report to xamarin bugzilla https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57863

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Do other bindings work correctly, i.e. is it definitely trying to check for null that is the issue?

Comment: I don't see any errors and yes other bindings are working correctly.

Comment: I've just tested it and also get the same issue...it may be a Xamarin bug.  One workaround would be to use a Converter that implements IValueConverter?

Comment: Thanks for testing it. Converter might be a good workaround. I have filed a bug to xamarin bugzilla: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57863

Answer (score 21):

I know this is an old thread, but here is the solution:

Btw, you wouldn't need `Isvisible="True"` in the StackLayout because the default value is true.

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="True">
    <StackLayout.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout"
                        Binding="{Binding MyObject, TargetNullValue=''}"
                        Value="">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </StackLayout.Triggers>

    ...

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: FYI - TargetNullValue='' seems to break in Xamarin Forms 5+ when I'm trying to use it on a Label.

Comment: @nixkuroi are you seeing a specific error or is it just not working as expected?

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException when using TargetNullValue=''. Instead of using "empty" I changed to a zero and it worked for me.

Comment: I had to use FallbackValue instead of TargetNullValue to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use converter and set to it its work for me. Lets try below code.

**Converter Code**

```
public class NullValueBoolConverter: IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (value is string)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                if (value == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

**And bind with IsVisible property like below :**

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Registerclosure.Notes, Converter={Helpers:NullValueBoolConverter}}">
</StackLayout>
```

**Don't Forgot below line in header**

xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"

Comment: converter will not be called if binding is null , this is made by xamarin design

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug with Xmarin Forms  [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57863)

Comment: Yes I filed it. I have edited the question now to include the bugreport link.

Answer (score 1):

Just optimizing the code in previous solution

```
  public class NullValueBoolConverter : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
  {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                string val = value as string;
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val);
            }

            return !(value == null);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
  }
```